# What's the difference betweene Jboss Fuse and Fuse Esb?

Tags: jboss, esb, jbossfuse, fuseesb

What's the différence between "[Jboss Fuse](http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/overview/)" and  "[Red Hat JBoss Fuse](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/fuse)"

Are they the same? 
Both are from Red Hat , both are based on Jboss , and both links are from 2016.
Can you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No differences, the latter comes with the Red Hat customer support.